# AxWMPLib - Played video playing state get flipped after exiting from full screen

Tags: c#, media-player, wmplib

I am trying to create a video player using [**AxWMPLib**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd564585%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

But I am getting a problem when I am exiting full screen from media player using double click on media player.

If user double clicks on windows media player in full screen:

1. If then the video was playing, it becomes paused.
2. If the video was paused, it becomes playing.

In minimum screen mode (not full screen).

I don't use any advanced options in it, it is a simple media player.

My code is like this-

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using WMPLib;

namespace VideoPlayer
{
    public partial class VideoPlayer : Form
    {
        public VideoPlayer()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            player_VideoPlayer.uiMode = "none";
            player_VideoPlayer.URL= "C:\\try.mp4";
            player_VideoPlayer.Ctlcontrols.play();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: we can use this- `player_VideoPlayer.ClickEvent+=ClickEventFunction;` to override click event on player, it is single click. But we need double click event.  The double click event provided here - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd562411%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 is not working